# Which chart library does this website use?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I am wondering which chart library this website uses: https://digitalik.net/btc/

Is it a specific JS library, or just some HTML 5 stuff? Also, I'd be interested to learn how you found it out?
Judging from the source code, the charts seem to be in some div containers, but I didn't fully understand the source code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at the HTML source code. There might be a link to a `.js` library. In your case there is, namely, `<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>`. Plotly?